# (cv2,capture) object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv

Basically, this code will detect object's motion in the scene. When the motion is detected, a red rectangle frame will track the object's motion. But, I added a new function into the code which is frame differencing. In general it is thresholding. When i run the code it says:"cv2.capture" object is not callable.

```
import cv2.cv as cv

class Target:

    def __init__(self):
        self.capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
        cv.NamedWindow("Target", 1)

    def run(self):
        # Capture first frame to get size
        ret, current_frame = self.capture()
        previous_frame = current_frame

        frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
        frame_size = cv.GetSize(frame)
        color_image = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), 8, 3)
        grey_image = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), cv.IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1)
        moving_average = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame), cv.IPL_DEPTH_32F, 3)

        first = True

        while True:
            current_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
            previous_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(previous_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    

            frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(current_frame_gray,previous_frame_gray)

            closest_to_left = cv.GetSize(frame)[0]
            closest_to_right = cv.GetSize(frame)[1]

            color_image = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)

            # Smooth to get rid of false positives
            cv.Smooth(color_image, color_image, cv.CV_GAUSSIAN, 3, 0)

            if first:
                difference = cv.CloneImage(color_image)
                temp = cv.CloneImage(color_image)
                cv.ConvertScale(color_image, moving_average, 1.0, 0.0)
                first = False
            else:
                cv.RunningAvg(color_image, moving_average, 0.020, None)

            # Convert the scale of the moving average.
            cv.ConvertScale(moving_average, temp, 1.0, 0.0)

            # Minus the current frame from the moving average.
            cv.AbsDiff(color_image, temp, difference)

            # Convert the image to grayscale.
            cv.CvtColor(difference, grey_image, cv.CV_RGB2GRAY)

            # Convert the image to black and white.
            cv.Threshold(grey_image, grey_image, 70, 255, cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)

            # Dilate and erode to get people blobs
            cv.Dilate(grey_image, grey_image, None, 18)
            cv.Erode(grey_image, grey_image, None, 10)

            storage = cv.CreateMemStorage(0)
            contour = cv.FindContours(grey_image, storage, cv.CV_RETR_CCOMP, cv.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
            points = []

            while contour:
                bound_rect = cv.BoundingRect(list(contour))
                contour = contour.h_next()

                pt1 = (bound_rect[0], bound_rect[1])
                pt2 = (bound_rect[0] + bound_rect[2], bound_rect[1] + bound_rect[3])
                points.append(pt1)
                points.append(pt2)
                cv.Rectangle(color_image, pt1, pt2, cv.CV_RGB(255,0,0), 1)



            cv.ShowImage("Target", color_image)
            cv.ShowImage("frame_diff", frame_diff)


            # Listen for ESC key
            c = cv.WaitKey(7) % 0x100
            if c == 27:
                break

if __name__=="__main__":
    t = Target()
    t.run()
```

This is the original frame differencing code that I wanted transfer from:

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
ret, current_frame = cap.read()
previous_frame = current_frame

while(cap.isOpened()):
    current_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(current_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    previous_frame_gray = cv2.cvtColor(previous_frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)    

    frame_diff = cv2.absdiff(current_frame_gray,previous_frame_gray)

    cv2.imshow('frame diff ',frame_diff)      
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

    previous_frame = current_frame.copy()
    ret, current_frame = cap.read()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call the `capture` object, but you can read from it by calling its `read` method. Changing your frame return code to:

```
ret, current_frame = self.capture.read()
```

Should fix this.

**Edit**:

The two lines:

```
ret, current_frame = self.capture.read()
previous_frame = current_frame
```

Will work for `VideoCapture` but not `CaptureFromCAM`. You apparently don't need them since you can take a frame by doing:

```
frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)
```

Comment: @LeeAndroid Oh, you're using `CaptureFromCAM` and  not `VideoCapture`, so `frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)` should do without the preceding two lines.

Comment: object is not iterable. Confused :(

Comment: ret,current_frame,frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)

Comment: No, just `frame = cv.QueryFrame(self.capture)` should do. Why do need multiple frames at the same time?